# Auto smooth by default

Tags: modeling, objects

When I'm creating new object auto smooth in Object data tab is always turned off and angle is 30. i need it to be on and 180 angle by default when i'm creating new object .Is there a way to do that? Thank you.

Comment: you can open a new file, enable Autosmooth with 180, then File > Save Startup File (ctrl U) to make this setup enable by default when you open a new file

Comment: Mb a don't know something,but you can set autosmooth only in object properties, and it changes for each new object when its created.